# Best option to store In-App Images in iOS

Tags: ios

First I should confess that I am completely new to iOS programming and would like to get an answer for a question which I was googling all the day.
     I would be having an app which will contain nearly about 500 images of png format with less size. How to store these images by categories inside the app? From what I learnt,

1. I can create a plist and map the images with strings (but not recommended by many if the data becomes huge)
2. creating a manual folder and storing the images (not sure how to do this..)

I have seen lots of codes on how to download and save the image from web or even from camera, but not sure what is the best way to store the in-app images which I have in hand in the app itself. Any sugggestions with sample code would be greatly helpful.

Comment: The App has it's own Documents directory. 
Ich would store it there.

Comment: You will not get one answer since there is none. Nor is there one way to go. It totally depends on all your requirements, I can add at least 20 more way to do it. You should really just figure out what you need and go from there.

Comment: @Fogmeister that would only work if the images are pre bundled. If they come from the web or camera Asset Catalog is not an option.

Comment: @rckoenes True. Ah... just seen the bit about "download and save". In that case... don't use asset catalog :D

Comment: @rckoenes: thanks for ur answer. Basically I will have 10 folders of images (each folder has 50 images).I just need to show these in grid view. Grid view will show 10 items and on click of an item, the internally stored 50 images will be displayed.I was thinking of using asset, but I don't know whether this is good option.In future,two or three folders would be downloaded from web.So, basically I don't know how to fit this in the app. You have said u have 20 ways to do so,kindly let me know one way which can be used to store in folders. Don't need a code, just point me in the right direction..

Answer (score 1):

Are you downloading the images? Will these images ever change? Do you have a lot of metadata for each image (you mentioned storing them by categories).

While this is not the only way to implement it, I've had luck implementing things like this using a CoreData model that has an `Image` entity with `category` and `filename` as properties. You can store the images in the `NSBundle` or anywhere you like as long as they are in the same directory to make it easier on you. Then make sure each filename is unique and maps correctly to the `CoreData` entity.

This allows you to also at any time, allow more images to be sent down or even replace them. Once you download new images, you add new entities to your `CoreData` without you needing to update any plist or mapping. You also gain access to NSPredicates with the CoreData fetchRequest, which will allow you to query the CoreData for images that fall under 1 category or even several categories.

The downside is that it requires additional set-up, namely learning CoreData and implementing it into your project.

Edit:

For doing something *right now* and very basic, the answer is easy to implement. Add the folders into your directory and make sure they have the target/are getting in the bundle. From there, add a pList that for each category lists the filenames of every image you're interested in.

Then when in the app they click on a category, you pull the plist and get the list of names as either a dictionary/array. Then you load all the images.

The downside to this is that you have to manually update the plist for any new changes and send it down to the phone from a server.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. will have a look at core data for sure. But this is helpful if am downloading and storing the images. The problem what i have in my hand is, i have set of images and need to know where and how to put it in the app. Will asset and plist mapping would be a good option? many people has said, not so.. I need a feasible way to put the images in the app now.. any suggestions for that?

Comment: In my opinion, asset and plist mapping is a bad way of doing it. You'll have to update the plist mapping for any addition you do to images. It is a shortcut and will be faster than implementing CoreData, but if you need to make changes down the road you will always have to update your mapping. For instance, if you push an update that has a new image out, you also have to push out a new plist. This will happen for every single update you do. It's a trade off of doing the right thing upfront or rushing something out the door

Comment: exactly.. so, what would be the feasible option?

Comment: I've given you a feasible long-term working solution that will automatically work for future updates. It really depends on what you're going to do with this code long term. Any *good* solution will require time to do, but it sounds like you want a solution that you can put in now with as little work as possible. If so, the plist will work and is only a good solution if you don't change the images (add to/delete from). Even if you do change the images, it is still a workable solution. I've edited my answer to show how to do it with a plist.

Comment: thanks for updating. But, I do not want a quick solution. Code should not be touched for the future updates and that's my intention also. I will look into core data as per your suggestion.

Comment: Gotcha, I misunderstood then. If you're more familiar with sqlite then you can try writing sqlite3 commands instead of coreData. Going with this route will require either downloading a zip for future updates and parsing the directory to update the DB or having an API that returns the image path + metadata in a preferably JSON format.

Comment: Ahhh... though I completely dont know how to do this in iOS, I got your point. I am familiar with sqlite but iOS is new, so have to dig about this option.. thanks mate..